# FilterFactory2 overlaps/intersects

Tags: geoserver, geotools, wps, opengis

I am creating WPS for measuring area of two overlapping polygons. Its working fine but now I want to implement *FilterFactory2* . I am not sure if use Overlap or Intersect method and than, how to feed data into the filter. I found some examples and this is how far i come

```
    String overlayPolygonsWithFilter() throws IOException {

    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();

    String areas = "Object : Area of overlay";

    ShapefileDataStore sfds = new ShapefileDataStore(new URL("file:///F:\\GeoServer285\\data_dir\\data\\test_data\\chranene_uzemi_cr.shp"));
    SimpleFeatureSource fs = sfds.getFeatureSource();

    ShapefileDataStore sfds2 = new ShapefileDataStore(new URL("file:///F:\\GeoServer285\\data_dir\\data\\test_data\\lesy_cr.shp"));
    SimpleFeatureSource fs2 = sfds2.getFeatureSource();

    SimpleFeatureCollection sfc = DataUtilities.collection(fs.getFeatures());
    SimpleFeatureCollection sfc2 = DataUtilities.collection(fs2.getFeatures());

    ListFeatureCollection sfcList = new ListFeatureCollection(sfc);
    ListFeatureCollection sfcList2 = new ListFeatureCollection(sfc);

    SimpleFeatureIterator sfi = sfcList2.features();

    double sum = 0;
    while (sfi.hasNext()) {

        SimpleFeature sf = sfi.next();
        MultiPolygon mp2 = (MultiPolygon) sf.getDefaultGeometry();

        Filter filter = ff.intersects(ff.property("THE_GEOM"), ff.literal(sf.getDefaultGeometry()));

        SimpleFeatureIterator sfi2 = sfc.subCollection(filter).features();
        // TODO while using ListFeatureCollection, FAIL ON ROW BELOW
        //SimpleFeatureIterator sfi2 = sfcList.subCollection(filter).features();

        Polygon p2 = (Polygon) mp2.getGeometryN(0);

        // TODO FAIL ON ROW BELOW
        while (sfi2.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature sf2 = sfi2.next();
            MultiPolygon mp3 = (MultiPolygon) sf2.getDefaultGeometry();
            Polygon p3 = (Polygon) mp3.getGeometryN(0);
            Geometry p4 = p2.intersection(mp2);
            if (p4.getArea() != 0) {
                sum += p4.getArea();
                areas = areas + "\n" + p4.getArea()+ " : " + p2.getArea() + " : " + p3.getArea();
            }
        }
        sfi2.close();
    }
    sfi.close();

    sfds.dispose();
    sfds2.dispose();

    return "Objects found: " + areas + "\nTotal sum: " + sum;
}
```

I commented rows where its failing.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.geotools.filter.expression.PropertyAccessorFactory: Provider org.geoserver.wps.property.ExecutionStatusAccessorFactory could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.geotools.filter.expression.PropertyAccessors.<clinit>(PropertyAccessors.java:51)
    at org.geotools.filter.AttributeExpressionImpl.evaluate(AttributeExpressionImpl.java:213)
    at org.geotools.filter.AttributeExpressionImpl.evaluate(AttributeExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.getGeometries(GeometryFilterImpl.java:108)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.evaluate(GeometryFilterImpl.java:237)
    at org.geotools.data.store.FilteringFeatureIterator.hasNext(FilteringFeatureIterator.java:60)
    at cz.val0065.wps.Process.overlayPolygonsWithFilter(Process.java:129)
    at cz.val0065.wps.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geoserver/platform/ServiceException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.geoserver.wps.property.ExecutionStatusAccessorFactory.<clinit>(ExecutionStatusAccessorFactory.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 more
C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: I would start by writing a method that does the calculation and then wrap that in the process implementation once it is working correctly.

Comment: I have working process here https://github.com/val0065/WpsDP/blob/master/src/cz/val0065/wps/Process.java, its method overlayPolygons() but the problem is, it takes too long to calculate, so i want to try to make it quicker with that filter.

Comment: I find out, code can be compiled, but it gives totally different results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to work out exactly what you are trying to do, this code will calculate the overlap (intersection) between **all** of the polygons in each of the shapefiles. Note `FilterFactory2` is a factory that already exists there is no need to "implement" it.

Also note this will be slow as it calculates N*M intersections for the N polygons in the first file against each of the M polygons in the second.

```
package spike;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.filter.Filter;
import org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory2;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

public class Overlaps {
  FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ShapefileDataStore sfds = new ShapefileDataStore(
        new URL("file:///F:\\GeoServer285\\data_dir\\data\\test_data\\chranene_uzemi_cr.shp"));

    ShapefileDataStore sfds2 = new ShapefileDataStore(
        new URL("file:///F:\\GeoServer285\\data_dir\\data\\test_data\\lesy_cr.shp"));


    Overlaps me = new Overlaps();

    double sum = me.process(sfds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(), sfds2.getFeatureSource().getFeatures());
    System.out.println(sum);
  }

  public double process(SimpleFeatureCollection one, SimpleFeatureCollection two) {
    double sum = 0;

    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr2 = two.features()) {

      while (itr2.hasNext()) {

        SimpleFeature sf = itr2.next();
        Geometry geom2 = (Geometry) sf.getDefaultGeometry();

        Filter filter = ff.intersects(ff.property(one.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName()), ff.literal(geom2));

        try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr1 = one.subCollection(filter).features()) {
          while (itr1.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature feature = itr1.next();
            Geometry geom1 = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
            Geometry overlap = geom1.intersection(geom2);
            if (overlap.getArea() != 0) {
              sum += overlap.getArea();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return sum;
  }

}
```